# Biot-Savart law and surface charges on moving plates

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, classical-electrodynamics

> Question:
>   A large parallel plate capacitor with uniform surface charge $\sigma$ on the upper plate and $-\sigma$ on the lower plate is lower with a constant speed V as in the figure. Use Ampere's law with the appropriate Amperian loop to find the magnetic field between the plates and also above and below them.

By Ampere's law:

$\vec{\bigtriangledown }\times \vec{B}=\mu_{0}\vec{J}+\mu_{0}\epsilon\frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}$

The current sheet due to the moving surface charge plate is $\vec{K}=\left \langle 0,\pm\sigma,0  \right \rangle$.
Since the charges are constant across the surface, it can be expected that the current is steady/ constant so this is a case of magnetostatic.
Additionally, the fact that the current is on the x-y plane suggests there is no x and y dependence.

By the Biot-Savart law for surface current:

$\vec{B}\left ( \vec{r} \right )=\frac{\mu_{0}}{4 \pi}\int \frac{\vec{K}\left ( \vec{r'} \right )\times \hat{\eta}}{\left \| \vec{\eta} \right \|^{2}}da'$

where $\vec{\eta}=\vec{r}-\vec{r'}$
where $\vec{r}$ is the vector distance from the origin to the field point and $\vec{r'}$ is the vector distance from origin to the source charge.

We expect the magnetic field not to be in the $\hat{y}$ direction due to the cross product in the integrand.

[image: Fig]

However, I do understand why the magnetic field does not have a $\hat{z}$ direction. In fact, I am unfamiliar with the right hand rule for 'surface' current.

**Edit**:I figured that if I rotate the plate 180 degrees about the z-axis in the CCW direction, the direction of the surface current changes-opposite to the direction of the surface current before the rotation-but the magnetic field continues to point in the positive z-axis which is a contradiction.

Would someone kindly clear my doubts?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did not quite understand what exactly your question was. can you state it once again ? just the part where you're confused .

Comment: Yes, are you interested in the magnitude of the B-field in space or the direction?

Comment: @JayJay I am interested in the direction of the B-field in space. I understand the B-field has no y component direction. This comes from the mathematics of the cross product in the integrand. But what about the B-field having no z component direction? I suggested that the B-field cannot have a z-component direction because if it did a contradiction arises. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @GeeJay   "I figured that if I rotate the plate 180 degrees about the z-axis in the CCW direction, the direction of the surface current changes-opposite to the direction of the surface current before the rotation-but the magnetic field continues to point in the positive z-axis which is a contradiction.".... could you explain what's the contradiction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wasn't sure how to proceed with this question, since the figure makes it seem like a finite capacitor and does not provide the dimensions. I will attack the problem with the assumption that the capacitor is infinite in the x-y plane.

Now, there is one way to figure out the direction of the net B-field: logical reasoning as Griffiths does (Introduction to Electrodynamics, 3rd Edition, p.226, example 5.8) for the case of **one** plate with surface current $K$. **Note that the current is in the +x direction in this example.**

[image]

> First of all, what is the direction of B? Could it have any x -component? No: A glance
>   at the Biot-Savart law (5.39) reveals that B is perpendicular to K. Could it have a z -component?
>   No again. You could confirm this by noting that any vertical contribution from a filament at
>   +y is canceled by the corresponding filament at —y. But there is a nicer argument: Suppose
>   the field pointed away from the plane. By reversing the direction of the current, I could make
>   it point toward the plane (in the Biot-Savart law, changing the sign of the current switches the
>   sign of the field). But the z -component of B cannot possibly depend on the direction of the
>   current in the xy plane. (Think about it!) So B can only have a y -component, and a quick
>   check with your right hand should convince you that it points to the left above the plane and
>   to the right below it.

Griffiths then proceeds to make an Amperian loop, and find the B-field:

[image]

So, in your case, where the current in in **+y direction** you are correct that there cannot be a z component. **There will only be an x component**.

Now for the real fun. Since you put that Biot-Savart law for surface current in your question, I thought I might as well use it and go ahead and show that the net B-field is in the x-direction the integration way. So here goes

We know,

$\vec{B}\left ( \vec{r} \right )=\frac{\mu_{0}}{4 \pi}\int \frac{\vec{K}\left ( \vec{r'} \right )\times \vec{\eta}}{\left \| \vec{\eta} \right \|^{3}}da'$

where $\vec{\eta}=\vec{r}-\vec{r'}$
where $\vec{r}$ is the vector distance from the origin to the field point and $\vec{r'}$ is the vector distance from origin to the source charge.

**K**=$\sigma$v$\hat{y}$

Let us take any point ($\ x_1,y_1,z_1$) that we want to find the net B-field at.  We find the field here due to the surface current at the general point  ($\ x,y,0 $)

$\vec{\eta}=(x_1-x)\hat{x}+(y_1-y)\hat{y}+z_1\hat{z}$

${\vec{K} ( \vec{r'}  )\times \vec{\eta}}$=$\sigma$v$\hat{y} \times ((x_1-x)\hat{x}+(y_1-y)\hat{y}+z_1\hat{z}) $ =$z_1\hat{x}-(x_1-x)\hat{z} $

Now for the integral, which I take over the entire xy plane:

$\vec{B}\left ( \vec{r} \right )=\frac{\mu_{0}\sigma v}{4 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\frac{\vec{K}\left ( \vec{r'} \right )\times \vec{\eta}}{( {(x_1-x)^{2}+(y_1-y)^{2}+{z_1}^{2}} )^{3/2}}dxdy$=
$\frac{\mu_{0}\sigma v}{4 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\frac{z_1\hat{x}-(x_1-x)\hat{z}}{( {(x_1-x)^{2}+(y_1-y)^{2}+{z_1}^{2}} )^{3/2}}dxdy$

Separating this integral into two separate ones, one that finds the field in the x-direction and one in the z-direction: the latter comes out to be zero and the former:

$\frac{\mu_{0}\sigma v}{4 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\frac{z_1\hat{x}}{( {(x_1-x)^{2}+(y_1-y)^{2}+{z_1}^{2}} )^{3/2}}dxdy =\frac{\mu_{0}\sigma v}{4 \pi}*\frac{2 \pi z}{|z|} $

So, you get:

$ \vec{B}=\frac{\mu_0\sigma v\hat{x}}{2}                  (z>0 $, ie-above the positive plate)

$ \vec{B}=-\frac{\mu_0\sigma v\hat{x}}{2}                 (z<0 $, ie-below the positive plate)

Extending these results to both plates (adding the contributions from both $\sigma $ and -$\sigma $ you will find that

$ \vec {B}=-\mu_0\sigma$v$\hat{x}$  (between the plates)

$ \vec {B}=0 $                            (above and below)

I hope I addressed all your doubts!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think it addresses all the issues @Physkid had very well.